# How to inherit from a field in a table to another field

Tags: lua

I'm starting now in Lua and I came across a problem, I searched about it and didn't find anything related

I have a lua table, where inside I have several fields.

my table:

```
MyTable = {
    ["coreal_1-1"] = {
        enable = true,
        speed = 1.5,
        size = 2.5,
    },
    ["oreal_1-1"] = {
    
    },
    ["capt_2-3"] = {
        enable = true,
        speed = 1.8,
        size = 2.1,
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried to use setmetatable for `oreal_1-1`, but it doesn't work for table fields as far as I've seen

I'm looking for a way where I can inherit a field to another

For example I want to inherit all fields inside `coreal_1-1` field to `oreal_1-1` and also be able to insert new entries

Just an example, to make it better to understand

```
["oreal_1-1"] = {
   //Here would come something to inherit
   speed = 2.0 // Speed ​​is rewritten to value 2.0
}
```

Is this possible, and how can I do this?

Comment: After the table `MyTable` is constructed, you need to "deepcopy" `coreal_1-1` into `oreal_1-1` and after that you can add new fields.

Comment: Or you can just set a metatable `MyTable.oreal_1-1 = setmetatable({}, {__index=MyTable.coreal_1-1})` and after that add/redefine fields

Comment: @ESkri Could I use something like `MyTable["oreal_1-1"] = MyTable["coreal_1-1"]` as well to be able to inherit ?

Comment: No.  That would just copy a reference to the same table.

Comment: @ESkri Got it, one last question, the tables that are inherited when printing content those that are inherited are not shown

Is it possible to display? Example http://tpcg.io/_BHC0LF

Comment: `pairs` does not work for inherited content.  You should define `__pairs` metamethod to change `pairs` behavior.  Or you may write more complex function for printing content.  (There is no standard function in Lua for displaying table content, so you have to write your own anyway)